# Linking OpenCV 2.4.5 in Visual Studio 2012 Debug vs Release

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, linker

I'm working on a project in Visual Studio 2012 that uses OpenCV 2.4.5. I have built the library myself without errors, both in Debug and Release modes. I am able to compile and link my project correctly in Debug mode and it runs just fine in Debug mode. However, when I switch to Release mode, it no longer links. I get 120 unresolved external symbol errors, all OpenCV functions.

I have double checked my project property settings in Release mode to make sure I am pointing the linker to the Release versions of the library (opencv_core245.lib instead of opencv_core245d.lib). I have double checked that I specified the library directory properly and verified that the *.lib files I specify in Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies are present in the directory. All property settings are identical to Debug mode save for the library file names.

I have run out of ideas on how to solve this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the box for "Additional Dependencies" was empty under the Linker->Input settings, even though I see the *.lib files when I edit it. I had all these settings in an external property page for it to be portable between projects, but the overall project settings did not update to include the %(Additional Dependencies) variable.

Once I included %(Additional Dependencies), the project linked successfully in Release mode as well as Debug mode.